# Undelete an automatically deleted question or simply re-ask it?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking more because I couldn't find a guideline on the correct behavior than because I care about the question itself.

I asked a question [about an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744812/defining-default-scope-for-find-in-path-pycharm) that was (incorrectly) downvoted by a user on account of 'questions about IDEs not belonging in Stack Overflow'. But they do. So 30 days later, the question is now automatically deleted and I received an answer from the IDE developer with something that I could maybe use to answer the question myself: [they opened an issue in their bugtracker about it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87037). I could at least edit my question with that so future people looking for it are redirected there.

The general point, though, is that I clicked on 'undelete' but It seems "4 more votes" (by, I assume, users with enough reputation to have the priviledge to see deleted questions) are needed for it to be restored. Quite honestly, I don't think that If I have to wait longer than a couple of days I will remember stuff like this *at all*.

So now I'm thinking if the easier method of just *re-asking the exact same question* with the answer, since I can do that immediately. Is that the **correct** way of doing it, though?

Comment: Surely you are missing the point.  The major problem is that your question did not get an answer.   That too few SO users thought the question was useful is secondary.  But not unrelated.  Questions without answers are like cowboys without guns, their life expectancy is low and they are just not that useful to get the herd into town.  Next time put a bounty on a question that you think needs to be answered and don't wait for a month to edit it.  And, of course, if you have an answer then you can always re-ask the question *and* post the answer.

Comment: Is voting to open on an automatically deleted question mandatory? For self-deleted questions, the OP can instantly recover it, right?

Comment: Well, it isn't closed. Just deleted. So why need to vote to reopen it? @jon

Comment: @Pat: sorry I meant voting to undelete, not re-open. I read the Help but it doesn't seem to mention this scenario.

Comment: @vmg it is undelete now!

Comment: @jon it need at least three votes to undelete the question and OP can give one of them.

Comment: If you can post it again, what is the sense of automatic deletion? Why not enough to close?

Answer (score -1):

I would have suggested asking a new question and posting your answer on the new question.

Voting to undelete (and asking on Meta) got the it re-opened, but that wasn't totally necessary. Since the question was already deleted, it's existence didn't take anything away from or add anything to the site and adding a new question wouldn't have been a duplicate (of an active Q), so no harm would have been done there.

In this scenario, whichever route you took, the result is the same; there is one active question about *Defining default scope for 'Find in Path' (PyCharm)* and subsequently an answer to your question. In other instances, if you vote to undelete, it might stay deleted, so you're better off just posting a new question... as long as it is, indeed, a valid and good question.

Answer (score -5):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that I think either way is fine.

Undeleting it is unlikely to happen unless you either post a question on Meta or convince people in chat. Asking a question on Meta is, of course, not OK as there is [a question for that already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309257/undeleting-automatically-deleted-question-now-that-i-have-an-answer-or-simply-re), so it would be a duplicate.

Asking for help in chat is probably the fastest way of getting a resolution if you're uncomfortable having deleted questions lying around.